# C++ casting void pointer to template class

Tags: c++, templates, casting

```
template <typename Type> struct testClass{
    Type value;
};

int main(){
    void* ptr = new testClass<int>;
    ptr->value = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work because the void pointer doesn't know what type it's pointing to, so I would have to cast it into the correct data type. I'm not sure how to do this for a template class however.

I tried:

```
(ptr<testClass>)->value = 0;
```

But the error says it's missing template arguments before '>'. I'm not sure how to cast it to testClass(int)

Comment: `static_cast<testClass<int>*>(ptr)->value = 0;`  avoid void pointers and casts altogether ... `void avoid`

Comment: The reason for the void pointer is because I'm trying to build a multi-type linked list, and as the pointers iterate through the list they might point to the class with "value" of different types, so I can't really specify the pointer type

Answer (score 4):

Despite the fact that there is no fundamental need to use `new` or `void`-pointers in the first place: `void*` points to - well - `void`. When initializing the pointer with the newly allocated object's address, type information is lost. A cast can retrieve it:

```
static_cast<testClass<int>*>(ptr)->value = 0;
```

However, I feel obliged to state again that you don't need `void` pointers. If you need to allocate the storage dynamically, use the exact type for the pointee:

```
testClass<int>* ptr = new testClass<int>;
```

Or let the compiler deduce it for you using `auto`.

```
auto ptr = new testClass<int>; // ptr has type testClass<int>*
```

And consider using smart pointers, e.g. [`unique_ptr`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.cppreference.com%2Fw%2Fcpp%2Fmemory%2Funique_ptr&ei=TDa8VNHpK4nraIHYgugK&usg=AFQjCNHDB_fFRgp8xfcM57_7Z7aNKoK4pQ&sig2=9ztg5rvrlHa7qu8Fzepa-Q&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d2s).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++11, you can use `auto`.

```
int main(){
    auto ptr = new testClass<int>;
    ptr->value = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

If you are using older compiler, you can use:

```
int main(){
    testClass<int>* ptr = new testClass<int>;
    ptr->value = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new operator allocates memory for a given type `T` and returns a pointer of type `T *` to this type.

In your case this type is `testClass<int>` so `new testClass<int>` returns `testClass<int> *`.

If you want to use the void pointer you can retrieve the type information using `static_cast<testClass<int> *>`.

```
static_cast<testClass<int> *>(ptr)->value = 0;
```

Some remarks on the usage of (void) pointers.

1. You don't need pointers here at all. (Your code leaks memory since objects created/allocated via new need to be freed/destroyed via `delete`.)

You can create objects on the stack instead which have automatic storage duration and get destroyed at the end of the current scope/function.

```
testClass<int> obj;
obj.value = 0;
```

2. You don't need `void` pointers here (if you need the dynamic allocation for whatever reason).

You can use the correct type instead.

```
testClass<int> * ptr = new testClass<int>;
ptr->value = 0;
delete ptr;
```

or with C++11

```
auto ptr = new testClass<int>; // where type of ptr is testClass<int>*
ptr->value = 0;
delete ptr;
```

3. You can use smart pointers instead of real pointers to handle destruction for you.

One example is `std::unique_ptr` handling sole ownership.

```
#include <memory>
template <typename Type> 
struct testClass{
  Type value;
};

int main ()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> p1(new testClass<int>);
  p1->value = 0;
  return 0;
}
```